# How to NOT use the _Layout page in a Web Pages website

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor, webmatrix

I have a webmatrix based website and have a test page. I need it to NOT be a part of the _SiteLayout page. How do I do this?

my dir:

```
root/
--assets/
--layouts/
----_SiteLayout.cshtml
--Default.cshtml
--Test.cshtml
```

As you can see above, there are two web pages in root dir, Default and Test. Default uses the _SiteLayout page. So does Test. But I don't want Test.cshtml to use _SiteLayout page. Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try set the Layout to null in the top of your Test.cshtml.

```
@{
Layout = null;
}
```